# Using chance.js inside AngularJS end to end tests

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm trying to generate some random data for my e2e tests. Seems that the only library   I found was [chance.js](http://chancejs.com/). But can't make it works. This is what I've tried so far:

```
describe('In the login page', function () {
  var chance = new Chance(); // ReferenceError: Chance is not defined

}
```

Then adding

```
beforeEach(function(){

        browser.executeScript(
            function() {
                return chance;
            }).then(function(_chance){
                chance = _chance; //It returns an object, but can't use any of the methods.

            });
        });
```

But if I try

```
beforeEach(function(){

        browser.executeScript(
            function() {
                return chance.email(); //Note this line here
            }).then(function(_chance){
                chance = _chance; //It returns an email

            });
        });
```

Thats all I have so far... any clue/idea?

Comment: do you have chance.js in a script tag before your tests?

Answer (score 3):

First, install chance.js in your project:

```
npm install chance --save-dev
```

This installs chance.js as a node module in your project. Then include it in your spec and instantiate:

```
var chance = require('../node_modules/chance').Chance();
```

Then call in your spec. For example:

```
it('should add a new friend', function() {
    var friendName = chance.string()
    friendPage.addFriend(friendName);

    expect(friendPage.inResults(friendName)).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see your answer until I posted mine. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

1. Okay first you need to download chance.js and add that file to your html directory
2. Second add **script src="chance.js"** in a proper script tag your   section
3. Within another script tag you should be able to use any of the functions that are listed on the website

working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c96x2cpa/

fiddle js code:

```
alert(chance.bool());
alert(chance.character());
alert(chance.floating());
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't answer my question. Using chance.in a regular page isn't the issue. Actually the problem is using it inside protractor tests (angularjs/e2e).

Comment: Oooooh okay, sorry misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

It was easy at the end :)

You just need to install chance as a node module.

```
npm install chance
```

Then require the node in the spec

```
// Load Chance
var Chance = require('chance');
```

And use it where ever you want

```
chance.email()
```

Enjoy!